# Django automated runserver and functional test

Tags: python, django

Im trying to use invoke module to automate my django functional tests, but I realised as the runserver command is rolling on my script waits until its finished to run the next command

```
from invoke import task

    @task
    def runserver(c):
        c.run('python manage.py runserver')
    
    @task
    def test(c):
        c.run('python functional_test.py')
    
    @task(runserver, test)
    def build(c):
        pass
```

I wanted to run both simultaneously, maybe with async or threding but cant figure  out how.

Comment: You could try doing a start_new_thread decorator: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/python-multithreading-for-python-django/ ..I find alot of success using them, very easy. I believe you'd just place it below the `@task` one, but I've never used this invoke package before

Comment: @Nealium i ended up using your hint with Pebble, worked really well as it makes threading very easy. The original idea from the blog was giving me some error which i couldnt debug fast

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction!- and then not do any of the actual work ;)

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this in python rather than bash or powershell or similar for your OS?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, I'm lazy and didnt wanted to open two terminals. In fact I found out Django already provides what I wanted (only write "python manage.py test") to do it all with LiveTestCase class. I'll edit my own answer right now to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following code, with the idea [@Nealium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10229768/nealium) gave but with [Pebble](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/1.1.0/) module:

```
from time import sleep
from invoke import task
from pebble import concurrent
import os

@task
def runserver(c,ip=None):
    if ip:
        ip_addr = ip
    else:
        ip_addr = None
    @concurrent.thread
    def build(c):
        if ip_addr:
            c.run(f'python manage.py runserver {ip_addr}:8091')
        else:
            c.run('python manage.py runserver')
        sleep(3)
                    
    @concurrent.thread
    def start():
        with open('build.txt','w') as file:
            file.write("Build done")
        c.run('python functional_test.py')
    
    build_future = build()
    start_future = start()
    
    build_done = False
    while not build_done:
        sleep(1)
        try:
            with open('build.txt', 'r') as file:
                content = file.read()
                if 'Build done' in content:
                    build_future.cancel()
                    build_done = True
        except:
            pass
    os.remove('build.txt')
    start_future.result()
```

- Like this we can just call in terminal "invoke runserver" or "inv
  runserver" (or change it to "build"  if you like) and it will do what
  it has to do and finish the test+server. I had to do the "build.txt"
  file because there's two terminals (django server and the test) and one
  needed to know when the other was up.
- We can also pass --ip arg, like: "invoke runserver --ip=0.0.0.0", the
  port its fixed but you got the idea

EDIT 1: Turns out Django already provided want I wanted with [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) class. I just didnt want to open two terminals (one to run the server locally and another to type "python manage.py test") as I intend to make a CI workflow

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class LoginViewTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('-headless')
        manager = GeckoDriverManager().install()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=FirefoxService(manager))
        self.driver = driver
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='testuser',
            email='testuser@example.com',
            password='testpassword'
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_login_sucess(self):
        #Trying to reach the login page
        self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + '/login')
        
        #Assert login title is correct 
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.title,'Login')

        #[... continues test]
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `LiveServerTestCase`. This is a great find! Thanks for posting this.